# How to run a query in controller based on radio button value in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have 2 radio buttons 1-selected, 2-none. I need to run queries in the controller if the radio button 1 is selected from the view and radio button 2 is selected from the view

Comment: Please provide the efforts you made so far, in terms of code or explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On select one option (by the user), it generates a ajax request to the controller(You may do it with javascript/Jquery), than execute the action with the query in your controller, this function for controller generate a response to your page, that can generate a response by ajax or do an action in PHP. If you give more informations we can give more details how to do it :)